# Автоматическое изменение размера datagridview на форме и размера ячеек при программном заполнении

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две формы. На первой форме датагрид с базой аксес. На второй форме датагрид, где заполняются заголовки в виде квадратной матрицы ( [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531862/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-datagridview) ). Как сделать, чтобы грид т ячейки автоматически изменяли размеры в зависимости от текста, а то получается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Нужно пробовать типа такого:

```
gridview.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
gridview.AutoResizeColumns();

gridview.AutoSizeRowsMode =
    DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
gridview.AutoResizeRows(
    DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCellsExceptHeaders);
```